# Баг в Firefox при выполнении JS?

Tags: javascript, firefox, отладка

Имеем следующий код:

```
    /// Waiting until the script is loaded
    initAddThisEvent(); /// 1

    function initAddThisEvent() {
        if (window.addthisevent) { /// 2
            try {
                window.addthisevent.settings({ /// 3
                    /// some options
                });
            } catch (e) {
                window.console.log(e); /// 4
            }
        } else {
            setTimeout(initAddThisEvent, 100); /// 5
        }
    }
```

Этот код находится в теге script, который расположен сразу за другим, который инициализирует объект addthisevent.

```
    <script src="lib.js"></script>
    <script>/// code above</script>
```

Если запустить этот код в Chrome, то шаги будут следующие: 1, 2, 3 - все как и задумано. Но в Firefox начинается веселье. 1-3 шаги выполнятся как полагается. Но потом 3 шаг выполнится еще раз. После мы попадем в 4 шаг, который не отработает. То есть в консоли я не вижу, чему равно и какого типа переменная e. А далее, что ну просто взрывает мозг, мы попадем в шаг 5, который тоже не отработает. Вывод такой сделал потому, что повторного вызова функции не происходит.

Вывод я сделал такой, что это какой-то баг в Firefox. Причем скорее всего именно самого Debugger. Хотя может быть и нет.

Итак вопрос. Вам что-нибудь известно об этом?

Comment: без кода, который воспроизвел бы проблему ничего сказать нельзя, приведенный код вполне нормален и в firefox отрабатывает без ошибок. Возможно стоит добавить больше выводов в лог

Comment: А почему вы не допускаете мысли, что если ваш код неправильно работает, то проблема в коде, а не в браузере, операционной системе или там законах физики?